# Python progress bar for python functions

Tags: python, progress-bar

I want to add a progress bar that shows the progress of the executing function. The function imports data from a postgresql dataset and finally draw a bar_chart of percentages of each segments.

Here is my code:

```
class RfmTable:

def __init__(self,table_name,start_date,end_date):
    self.table_name = table_name
    self.start_date = start_date
    self.end_date = end_date
    self.quintiles = {}

def rfm_chart(self):        
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=database_name, user=user_name,                           
                        password=password_info, host=host_info, port=port_info)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(...) #table information
    a = cursor.fetchall()

    # rfm analysis 
    # draw the chart
    for i, bar in enumerate(bars):
            value = bar.get_width()
            if segments_counts.index[i] in ['重要价值用户']:
                bar.set_color('firebrick')
            ax.text(value,
                    bar.get_y() + bar.get_height()/2,
                    '{:,} ({:}%)'.format(int(value),
                                       int(value*100/segments_counts.sum())),
                    va='center',
                    ha='left'
                   )
    return plt.show()
```

So what is a good way to add a progress bar to the function?

Answer (score 1):

[tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/) progress bar is probably the most featured progress bar for python. You can install it simply with `pip install tqdm`.

The following code demonstrates how easy it is to use.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This is what it looks like after running the above code example in pycharm:

[image]

1: Percent Complete
2: Progress Bar
3: Current Iteration out of Total Iterations
4: The Elapsed Time
5: The Estimated Remaining Time
6: Number of Iterations Processed per Second

Answer (score 0):

Using `rich`, we can add a progress bar that updates when given a function. Here's an example:

```
from rich.progress import Progress
import time
import inspect

def run(func, sleep=0):
    update = lambda progress, task: progress.update(task, advance=1)

    function = inspect.getsource(func)
    mylist = function.split('\n')
    mylist.remove(mylist[0])
    length = len(mylist)
    for num, line in enumerate(mylist):
        mylist[num] = line[8:] + "\nupdate(progress, task)\ntime.sleep(sleep)" #update the progress bar

    myexec = ''
    for line in mylist:
        myexec += line + '\n'

    with Progress() as progress:
        task = progress.add_task("Working...", total=length)
        exec(myexec)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def myfunc():
        #chose to import these modules for progress bar example since they take a LONG time to import on my computer
        import pandas
        import openai

    run(myfunc)
```

I'm not going to explain fully how this works, but basically the function `run()` takes another function as an argument, and also how much to sleep between updating the progress bar. We then turn the function into a string using `inspect`, and add our extra stuff to update the progress bar after each line of the function, and run the function using `exec()`.

While this code is a little inefficient (especially since it uses `exec()`), it definitely works. I recommend saving this as a file, maybe call it `progress_bar`? Then you can run this progress bar from anywhere in your python files, using the `run()` function.

So in your case, I'd assume you'd want:

```
from name_of_progress_bar_module import run

run(rfm_chart) #run the function, with default sleep time 0 between progress bar updating
```

You should probably note that `rich` looks best in the terminal. Otherwise...it works...but it doesn't look great.